# Subversion: Tag and commit modified files at once

Tags: eclipse, svn, tags, commit

I want to do something like this from within Eclipse: http://svn.collab.net/viewvc/svn?view=rev&revision=33845

I use Subversive 0.7.5 with the Native JavaHL 1.5.3 (r33570) Connector.

I tried to change something in a my working copy of a branch i'd like to tag and creating a Tag with Team -> Tag... But I got the error message:

> Tag operation for some of selected resources failed.
>
> A path under version control is needed for this operation

I tried only a tag name and one with full repository path. Both resulted in the same error.
This is the error I get:

```
*** Tag
svn copy "C:/workspace/some_branch" "http://server:8080/svn/project/tags/TagWithChange" -r WORKING -m "TagWithChange" --username "masi"
A path under version control is needed for this operation
```

Is it possible from within Eclipse?

How would you do something like this from the command line? See my own answer.

Though if I use the following at the command line I get an error:

```
svn copy "C:/workspace/some_branch" "http://server:8080/svn/project/tags/TagWithChange" -r WORKING -m "TagWithChange" --username "masi"
```

Error:

> svn: Syntax error in revision argument 'WORKING'

I'm using the svn client 1.5.4.

Answer (score 2):

Found the command line answer myself: 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

```
svn copy some_branch http://server:8080/svn/tags/TagWithChange -m"TagWithChange"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this same error when I used the Native JavaHL.  You can do two things to make your tag.

### A. Tag From SVN Respository Exploring Perspective

**SVN Repositories View**

1. Right click on the trunk you'd like to tag, New -> Tag.

---

### B. Update SVN Connector

**SVN Kit (SVN/1.5.5 SVNKit/1.2.2 (http://svnkit.com/) r5428)**

1. Install SVN Kit through software updates.
2. Window -> Prefs -> Team -> SVN -> SVN Connector -> SVN Connector

Answer (score 0):

I have always used Subclipse http://subclipse.tigris.org/ with eclipse - it is excellent and I think what all other plugins benchmark from.

It has been awhile since i used that particular setup, but subclipse will automatically add a new (non versioned file - one that hasn't been 'versioned', or put in the repository yet) meaning you shouldn't get your error.

Comment: We tried subclipse, but we deeply depend on the 1.5 merging feature and Subversive is more convenient for us.